# How to display elements of a product in a certain order

Tags: output, display, format

I have several product states, represented by a string of variables - for example, "ABC". I'd like to multiply this state by a constant, call it J, to which I don't want to pre-assign a value. Using J * "ABC" as my input, the output returns: ABC J. How do I get Mathematica to display the output as J ABC instead?

Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: `ToString@Unevaluated[J *"ABC" ]`, maybe

Answer (score 3):

You can use [NonCommutativeMultiply](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonCommutativeMultiply.html) instead, since it does not have the Orderless attribute:

```
J ** ABC
```

Comment: Can you expand on this answer?

Answer (score 2):

**Input**

```
sample = "ABC";
data = "J";
data <> " " <> sample
```

**Output**

```
"J ABC"
```

**Reference**

[StringJoin (<>)](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringJoin.html)
[String Manipulation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/StringManipulation.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend using `String`s that you append to to represent objects. Use instead a sequence of the names wrapped inside a custom `Head`, something like

```
state[a, b, c]
```

and can add to the state via `Prepend`, `Append`, or most generally `Insert` depending on where you want to add the new state:

```
Append[state[a, b, c], j]
(* state[a, b, c, j] *)
Prepend[state[a, b, c], j]
(* state[j, a, b, c] *)
Insert[state[a, b, c], j, 2]
(* state[a, j, b, c] *)
```

Alternatively,

```
SetAttributes[state, Flat]
state[state[a, b, c], d]
state[d, state[a, b, c]]
(* state[a, b, c, d] *)
(* state[d, a, b, c] *)
```