# How to obtain the output form as Cos[ω t] instead of Cos[t ω]?

Tags: output-formatting

When I type

```
Cos[ω t]
```

MMA gives me the output

```
Cos[t ω]
```

Is it possible to flip the positions of t and ω? Traditionlly, angular frequency comes first.

Comment: Well, if you write  $\omega \, t$ Mathematica replies with $t \, \omega$. It is built in Mathematica due to ordering of letters and symbols. Better not fight it as it makes no difference to the computation.  If you use HoldForm and such, then it will get into the way when you try to use the expression later on.  Cos[HoldForm[\[Omega]  t]]

Comment: Somewhat related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/186756/simplifying-simple-signed-expression-such-as-xx-1-to-x1-x-based-on-a

Comment: There are plenty of questions on this StackExchange about fiddling with the canonical order of symbols ([#9570](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9570/how-do-i-reassign-canonical-ordering-of-symbols), [#293193](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/293193/how-to-modify-the-order-of-symbols-to-make-the-result-more-logical), [#110606](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/110606/how-to-display-elements-of-a-product-in-a-certain-order) ...). But as @Nasser pointed out: Just get used to it, because all solutions are somewhat hacky ...

Comment: Note that this behaviour is of essential importance for the efficiency of Mathematica, because converting expressions to their "canonical form" (ie. canonical order in this case) allows faster expression manipulation, pattern matching, comparison ... If you will really work only with not very complicated examples, you can use this hackery: `$PrePrint = ReplaceAll[Cos[x_. t ω] :> Cos[HoldForm[x ω t]]]`.